# Facebook Sinatra app won't login

Tags: ruby, facebook, sinatra

I am trying to develop a Facebook Application using the Ruby Heroku pack provided. I have experimented with this before but just created a new app to develop. I am having an issue where I am unable to log in with the app. I click on a button to log in, but after the redirects, I find that nothing has happened. Once in every 20 or so attempts though, it will log me in correctly.

For those who've never used the Heroku hosting for Facebook, [here](https://github.com/heroku/facebook-template-ruby) is the template that gets installed. The only changes I have made were to modularize the app.

The relevant routing is as follows:

```
get "/auth/facebook" do
  session[:access_token] = nil
  redirect authenticator.url_for_oauth_code(:permissions => FACEBOOK_SCOPE)
end

get '/auth/facebook/callback' do
  session[:access_token] = authenticator.get_access_token(params[:code])
  redirect '/'
end
```

Has anyone ever experienced this before? If one would like to try themselves, [this](https://blooming-fortress-5933.herokuapp.com/) is the location of the app. I have a similar one running that doesn't exhibit this problem, so I really can't figure it out.

EDIT: I think I found the problem. I had set Unicorn preload_app to false, following [this piece of information](https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/no-data-with-unicorn) from New Relic. Setting preload_app to true has since fixed the problem. Unfortunately, I cannot remember why I set it to false in the first place (I have adapted some configuration stuff from a previous app). Maybe someone has better knowledge than myself.